# Rows of NA's Unexpectedly Returned

Tags: r

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I just can't see what's going wrong...

All I'm doing is simply making a dataframe (`all.score3`) of a larger dataframe (`all`). There are no all NA rows in the larger dataframe.

```
> class(all)
[1] "data.frame"
> table(all$Scoring, useNA = "always")

   1    2    3 <NA> 
 774  772  768    0 
> table(all$Resolution_Desc, useNA = "always")

No Response    Resolved        <NA> 
        293         962        1059 
> class(all$Resolution_Desc)
[1] "character"
> class(all$Scoring)
[1] "numeric"
> all.score3 <- all[all$Scoring == 3 & all$Resolution_Desc == "Resolved", ]
> dim(all.score3)
[1] 677  11
> tail(all.score3)
             ID1      ID2   Decile Scoring GroupNo  Treat Result1 Result2 flag50 Resolution_Desc nout_2way
NA.362      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
NA.363      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
NA.364      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
NA.365      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
NA.366      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
NA.367      <NA>      NA     NA      NA   <NA>  <NA>       NA       NA     NA            <NA>        NA
> cat("What ????")
What ????
```

It must be something to do with the `all$Resolution_Desc == "Resolved"` filter, because that also produces rows of `NA` if I only use that filter, but this is not true with the other:

```
all.score3 <- all[all$Resolution_Desc == "Resolved", ]
```

Why is this operation producing rows of `NA` that aren't present in the larger dataframe and which should not be present in the resulting dataframe anyway based on the conditions in the row filter?

Note -- I **can** work around this, such as with `sqldf` (or probably with `subset`), but I'd still like to understand what's happening here. I checked to make sure I'm using `&` the correct way, as opposed to using `&&` or something, and the resources I found seem to indicate that this should be correct...

Comment: Please clarify what the actual question is

Comment: Why is this operation producing rows of `NA` that aren't present in the larger dataframe and which should not be present in the resulting dataframe anyway based on the conditions in the row filter?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. How about posting a dput of "all"? Does the output remain the same if you do `all[all$Scoring == 3 & all$Resolution_Desc == "Resolved" & !is.na(all$Resolution_Desc), ]`?

Comment: This is kind of how R behaves when it is being subsetted by boolean expression that returns `NA`, it just keeps it there. Try `df <- data.frame(A = c("a", NA, "a")) ; df[df$A == "a", , drop = FALSE]`. Basically `df$A == "a"` returns `[1] TRUE   NA  TRUE` and R doesn't know what to do with the `NA` part so it keeps it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oooooo, right! I think you've nailed it. Can you please make that into an answer so that I can mark this as solved?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Sure. I would follow up on your request, but I think that David's comment just answered my question.

Comment: I think @JoshO'Brien once wrote an excellent answer on this but I can't seem to find it.